# Table td width.. in diffrent tr

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to set td width to diffrent px on each row.
So i generate a table tag with HTML.
Then i loop out a table with PHP.
If i put all td´s in one tr it works, but i got all td on same row.
I'd like to have just one td on each tr.

What i'm doing is building rectangles with diffrent length in a list.
Later on, they will be draggable.

**Code**

```
echo "<tr><td class='tdElements' id='".$row['id']."' style='width:".$row['element_langd']."px' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'>".$row['element_langd']."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: You can't do that, in  HTML td's in a column **have** to be the same width. If you need different widths then you're not building a table so don't use a table, use divs.

Comment: @Styphon ok, thanks. Then i´ll use div instead!

Comment: hello Styphon, column width can be different, check out my answer in this question.

Comment: @AnantaPrasadLoda you might want to re-read his question. You've done two cells in the same row of different width. The OP asked for two cells in the same *column* to be different width.

Comment: ok i got and thanks buddy styphon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo 
     "<div id='".$row['id']."' style='width:".$row['element_langd']."px'
       draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)'>"
       .$row['element_langd'].
      "</div>";
```

You can explicitly define the width of an individual `<div>` using css and, so each rectangle should be sized according to the `$row['element_langd']` value.